# Waterfall chart python matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am having a problem with waterfall. I took this chart from matplotlib site and added my own data frame with 2 simple columns with some integer numbers. My waterfall was produced but without numbers, just empty bars. I am a bit lost and I would appreciate any suggestions.

What I am trying to build is the custom waterfall that takes one dataframe with column names, values, and some values for filters like countries. I haven't found anything like that anywhere so I am trying to build my own.

```
import numpy as np;
import pandas as pd;
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter;

dataset = pd.read_csv('waterfall_test_data.csv')
#Use python 2.7+ syntax to format currency
def money(x, pos):
    'The two args are the value and tick position'
    return "${:,.0f}".format(x)
formatter = FuncFormatter(money)

#Data to plot. Do not include a total, it will be calculated
index = dataset['columns']
data = dataset['amount']
#Store data and create a blank series to use for the waterfall
trans = pd.DataFrame(data=data,index=index)
blank = trans.amount.cumsum().shift(1).fillna(0)

#Get the net total number for the final element in the waterfall
total = trans.sum().amount
trans.loc["net"]= total
blank.loc["net"] = total

#The steps graphically show the levels as well as used for label placement
step = blank.reset_index(drop=True).repeat(3).shift(-1)
step[1::3] = np.nan

#When plotting the last element, we want to show the full bar,
#Set the blank to 0
blank.loc["net"] = 0

#Plot and label
my_plot = trans.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, bottom=blank,legend=None, figsize=(15, 5), title="2014 Sales Waterfall")
my_plot.plot(step.index, step.values,'k')
my_plot.set_xlabel("Transaction Types")

#Format the axis for dollars
my_plot.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

#Get the y-axis position for the labels
y_height = trans.amount.cumsum().shift(1).fillna(0)

#Get an offset so labels don't sit right on top of the bar
max = trans.max()
neg_offset = max / 25
pos_offset = max / 50
plot_offset = int(max / 15)

#Start label loop
loop = 0
for index, row in trans.iterrows():
    # For the last item in the list, we don't want to double count
    if row['amount'] == total:
        y = y_height[loop]
    else:
        y = y_height[loop] + row['amount']
    # Determine if we want a neg or pos offset
    if row['amount'] > 0:
        y += pos_offset
    else:
        y -= neg_offset
    my_plot.annotate("{:,.0f}".format(row['amount']),(loop,y),ha="center")
    loop+=1

#Scale up the y axis so there is room for the labels
my_plot.set_ylim(0,blank.max()+int(plot_offset))
#Rotate the labels
my_plot.set_xticklabels(trans.index,rotation=0)
my_plot.get_figure().savefig("waterfall.png",dpi=200,bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: Take a look at [this github project](https://github.com/chrispaulca/waterfall).

Comment: It's pretty nice and easy, but I think it can't do what I am trying to achieve in the end. I would like to have waterfall with more than one net/summary bars in the middle, so I can walk a user through a multi-step process. To add more difficulty I also want to run it as a script in Power BI. From what I read I think only matplotlib can work there, otherwise I would use plotly.